# How do I restore a database dump to a Citus cluster?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, citus

While restoring a (`pg_dump`-produced) database dump, I get the following error:

> Cannot execute COPY FROM on a distributed table on master node

How can I work around this?

Comment: What partition method are you using? Can you please provide the commands you used to create your distributed table?

Answer (score 3):

`COPY` support was added in Citus 5.1, which [was released May 2016](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/18-sumedh-pathak/417-announcing-citus-51-improving-your-data-ingest-speed-and-experience) and is available in [the official PostgreSQL Linux package repositories](https://www.postgresql.org/download/) (PGDG).

Are you trying to load data via a `pg_dump` output? Creating distributed tables is slightly different than regular tables, and requires picking of partition columns and partitioning method. Take a look at [the docs](https://www.citusdata.com/docs/citus/5.1/dist_tables/append_distribution.html#creating-and-distributing-tables) to get more information on both.